# what is the meaning of BLE data rate 1Mbps?

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, bandwidth, baudrate, data-rate

I am using BLE HM10 module which is BLE 4.0 1Mbps

assume I have **1000000** **data bits** to send within a second, so I need 1Mbps bandwidth,

Is 1Mbps only for **Data bits**?

or 1Mbps means complete **Bluetooth packet bits + data bits**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, typically bandwidth is defined as the whole bits of the frame per second. So you get a payload of about 721 kbit/s (for Standard Bluetooth, but BLE should be close to that, due to restricted payload per package maybe less). You can calculate it by looking at the specifications and adding all data of a frame.